# replace backslash in redshift

Tags: sql, regex, replace, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I am working with a string column in redshift database where the instance of `\"` occurs multiple times in the same value.
I want to replace every occurrence of `\"` with `"`

For example, if a `string = \"name\"`

I want the output to be `string = "name"`

From what I have found, redshift does not allow the existence of a single backslash, and automatically converts it to a double backslash, but that is not happening in this case.

I have tried to use the `REPLACE()` with `REPLACE( string, '\"', '"' )` but it did not have any effect. Can the string being a JSON string have any bearing on the function of `REPLACE()`?

I have been trying to use `regexp_replace` but maybe I am not using the right regular expression, hence I am not able to solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to use a regexp, since you're just replacing fixed text, not a pattern. Juse use `REPLACE()`.

Comment: Does the column really contain double backslash, or is that how you're writing it in your queries? You need to double the backslash in a string literal to get a single backslash.

Comment: @Barmar  I have already tried the `REPLACE()` function, but it has not worked. This is the code I wrote - `REPLACE(string, '\"', '"')`
Does the fact that the column is a JSON string have any bearing on the replace function?


The column contains single backslash, the double backslashes were a typo that I have fixed.

Comment: @Barmar
Thanks for asking these questions, I was able to figure out a solution using `REPLACE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPLACE( string, '\\"', '"' )` seems works in this situation. I am guessing its because redshift doesn't allow a single backslash, but converts them to double backslash.

So, even though the string looked like `\"name\"` it was probably stored as `\\"name\\"` and hence putting a single backslash in the replace was not working.

EDIT: please read Bill's explanation in the comment below this reply

Comment: Backslash is the escape character for string input.  Redshift likely has a single backslash (non-repeating) in the column but when you add a single backslash to the input string Redshift uses this to escape the next  character.  So you need to have 2 backslashes - the first to escape the second.  This is how you enter a single backslash through SQL.